# Installing ROCm 4.0.1

Tags: pytorch, amd-rocm

With the latest update, Pytorch offers support for ROCm 4.0.1.
I've tried to install the latest version of ROCm using the guide on the official AMD [site](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html), but doing that I've only managed to install version 4.0.0.

As I understand at this step

```
wget -q -O - https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/rocm.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -

echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian/ xenial main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rocm.list
```

I should change the repository, but I can't figure out how.

Could someone help me with the exact lines that I should run in order to install 4.0.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the maintainers of the apt repository at https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian/, have not yet uploaded a package for rocm 4.0.1 there.

If you need this exact version, you can use the repository at http://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/4.0.1/ instead as recommended in the guide you linked to. Note that this will pin your rocm version to exactly this version without any automatic updates.

Comment: wget -q -O - http://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/4.0.1/ | sudo apt-key add -,

echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/4.0.1/ xenial main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rocm.list.

should my terminal commands look like that?

Comment: Not entirely. The gpg key is still on the same URL as before (i.e. your first command is unchanged). You would only adapt the repository URL in your second command.